# averages of numbers in lines of data file "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write some code that analyses a .csv file and then returns the average of the numbers on each line of the file as a list.

This is the code I have but I get this error which I don't understand!

```
def mean(values):
return sum(values) / len(values)


def line_averages(filename):
   """ compute the average value for every line, and return the average
   values in a list in the file "filename" """
   f = open(filename, "r")
   x = f.read()
   f.close()
   no_lines = x.split('\n')       # remove lines
   means = []
   for i in no_lines:
       no_commas = i.split(',')    # remove commas
       means.append(mean(no_commas))
   return means
```

An example file of data is:

```
1,2
1,1,1,1
-1,0,1
42,17
```

Comment: You are getting those values as strings. You have to cast the numerical string values to `int`. Also, why aren't you using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better done with the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. You can use the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) method which takes a file object as parameter and whose default delimiter is a comma:

Here's one way to do it using a *list comprehension* with the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object:

```
import csv

def line_averages(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        means = [sum(map(float, row))/len(row) for row in reader]
    return means
```

The [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement opens the file within a *context* and closes the file automatically once we move out of that context. You can wrap the list comp. in a `try/except` that handles [`ZeroDivisionError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ZeroDivisionError) should in case there are rows with zero length in your file.